# Proof verification of a number theory problem involving sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

$\textbf{Question:}$Does there exist an infinite sequence of integers
$a_1, a_2, . . . $ such that $gcd(a_m, a_n) = 1 $ if and only if $|m - n| = 1$?

$\textbf{My solution:}$Suppose we have a $n$ element sequence that satisfies the condition.say $a_1,\cdots,a_n$.
Now take $n-1$ distinct primes that divides none of the elements of this sequence.call the primes $p_1,\cdots,p_{n-1}$

Then the sequence $a_1p_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}p_{n-1},a_n$ also satisfies the condition.
Now,simply take $a_{n+1}=p_1....p_{n-1}$.
Then $a_1p_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}p_{n-1},a_n,a_{n+1}$ satisfies the condition.Hence,we can always increase the size of the sequence.

In addition $a,b$ with $(a,b)=1$ is a two element sequence that satisfies the condition.Hence we can form an infinite sequence that satisfies the given conditions.

If there is any flaw in my argument do tell me.

Comment: That only shows that you can find a finite sequence of any length with this property, not that you can find an infinite sequence.

Comment: I see a problem. If you apply this process an unbounded  number of times you end up with an infinite product.

Comment: In particular, you are wrong that $a_1,\dots,a_{n}$ statistics this condition. Rather $a_1p_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}p_{n-1},a_n$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: That part was a typo though.I think I got where I went wrong.

Comment: Should $a_n=p_1\cdots p_{n-2}$ to make it relatively prime to $p_{n-1}a_{n-1}?$ You can drop the $p_{n-1}$ completely, in fact. (But the proof still only shows that you can make such a sequence of any finite size.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you show the existsnece of arbitrarily long finite sequences. To construct an infintie sequence, you must come up with a construction that leaves the old terms unchanged.

This should work:
$$ a_n=p_{2n-1}p_{2n}\prod_{1\le i< 2n-3\atop i\equiv n\pmod 2}p_{i}$$
as $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ have no prime in common whereas one of $p_{2m-1},p_{2m}$ divides $a_n$ if $1\le m<n-1$.